# Output not appearing

Tags: unix, while-loop, case

The only problem I am having with this program is to print the result of the equation. When I try to multiply 3 * 3 then open the output file I get:

echo The operation is to multiply. The result of multiply 3 and 3 is

The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#check if number of arguments are 2

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Does not equal two arguments"
    echo "Usage $0 inputfile outputfile"
    exit 1
fi

#check if input file exists

if [ ! -e $1 ]; then
    echo "$1 not found!"
    exit 1
fi

#copy contents of first file to secon

cat $1 > $2

#While loop

while true
do
    clear
    #display the menu
    echo "                            University of Maryland                            "
    echo "                         App to solve integer equation                         "
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "                               1: Addition"
    echo "                               2: Subtraction"
    echo "                               3: Multiplication"
    echo "                               4: Division"
    echo "                               5: Modulo"
    echo "                               0: Exit"
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "                      Pleasa choose one of the following:                      "

    #take input from operation

    read N

    case $N in
        1) NAME="add";OP="+";;
        2) NAME="subtract";OP="-";;
        3) NAME="multiply";OP="*";;
        4) NAME="divide";OP="/";;
        5) NAME="modulo";OP="%";;
        0) echo "The program is ending" ; exit 0;;
        *) echo " Not an acceptable entry." ;continue;
    esac

    #take input numbers
    echo "Enter two numbers"
    read A
    read B

    #display value on screen and also append in the output file

    echo "The operation is to $NAME. The result of $NAME $A and $B is `expr $A $OP $B`


     echo The operation is to multiply. The result of multiply 3 and 3 is
echo "The operation is to $NAME. The result of $NAME $A and $B is `expr $A $OP $B` > $2


    done
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Everything seems to be in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered your original question:
The result appears just before the while-loop calls clear again.

See the other answer: Use "$OP" in double quotes, you do not want * to be replaced by a list of files.